# Netbeans is not showing source tab

Tags: netbeans

[image: Not showing Source tab]

Netbeans is not showing source tab, please help.

Comment: To change that, go in the Window menu, and re-add the source view (or whatever it's name is in NB) and re-add it. You most likely (accidentally) closed it, or it's hidden behind some other screen

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I had to delete the Netbeans Cache and User Directory. Once I did it worked fine.

you will find the cach in the path: C:\Users"user_name"\AppData\Roaming\Netbeans
delete all files in this folder

Answer (score 0):

It may be that for some reason the layout changed. I am not very familiar with NetBeans but I presume that there is an option to reset the layout under

Window -> Reset Windows

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As of now you are viewing Project view. You have to click on Files then you will be able to see what you want to see. :)
[image]

or still not visible follow following steps :

- User selects main menu Window.
- User clicks menu item Reset Windows and all views are reset to their defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Choose from IDE menu bar, Next to FILE---EDIT--VIEW---and then go to View option-- select show editor option
show "Editor Tool bar"(put tick mark to select)